# Use python through pythonthreehome and pythonthreedll?

Tags: microsoft-windows, vimscript-python, original-vim

I install python use msys2 in windows but i don't know how to put the path to vim

Here is my vim `--version`:
[image]

Here is where i install `python3`:

[image]

And `python3 dll`:

[image]

Vimrc config:

[image]

I use python for run python-formatter https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-autoformat

It raises this issue

[image]

But my vim8.2 has python support.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: _Strongly_ related: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8692

Comment: I want to post images for people easy to understand

Comment: Images usually make it harder for people to understand it. For example, a lot of text look too small for me now and I find it hard to read, also because I'm not used to dark backgrounds, which in general I personally find harder to read. If you copy/paste the text then it's almost much easier.

Comment: Anyway, I think k-takata already answered a few things on the Vim issue tracker? Did you try his suggestions? Did that not work?

Comment: Msys2 has a lot of vim related packages and I'm new to linux commands and it's hard to understand how to download python e.g. mingw-w64-x86_64-python and python, I don't know what is the difference. That's why I don't know how to set PATH properly in Windows